# Office 2016 fails installation on Win 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office-2016

I'm loosing my cool over this. I'm installing Office 2016 Standard (VLSP) license on Windows 10 Pro (Lenovo stock installed). Installation keeps failing. Same thing happened when I tried to install Office 2013 Standard on the same machine. Only Office 2010 would install properly. System had preinstalled Office 2016 Click-to-install which I since removed. I tried everything I could possibly find on the web including manual uninstall of Click-to-Install, removing folders from Task Scheduler and hot-fixing Windows Update, still to no success. Relevant setup log shown below. Please help!

```
MSI(INFO): 'CAQuietExec:  ERROR: The system cannot find the path specified.' 
MSI(INFO): 'CAQuietExec:  ' 
MSI(INFO): 'CAQuietExec:  Error 0x80070001: Command line returned an error.' 
MSI(INFO): 'CAQuietExec:  Error 0x80070001: CAQuietExec Failed' 
MSI(INFO): 'CustomAction CAOSMRegisterLogonTask.x64.1033 returned actual error code 1603 
           (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)' 
MSI(INFO): 'Action ended 11:39:23: InstallExecute. Return value 3.' 
MSI(COMMONDATA): 'Message type:  2, Argument:  0' 
MSI(COMMONDATA): 'Message type:  2, Argument:  0' 
MSI(COMMONDATA): 'Message type:  0, Argument:  1033' 
MSI(COMMONDATA): 'Message type:  1, Argument:  Microsoft Office OSM MUI (English) 2016'
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into some issues a while back pushing installs out.
First things first, delete all windows update temp files from
%windir%\SoftwareDistribution\Download
Second I would look for any older reg keys associated with the Lenovo office install. It should around the tree in 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\FilesPaths
Search through and look for any abnormal file paths. 
Backup and delete any keys.
Then run the installer. 
If it still fails try to run the setup.exe /admin to create a new adminfile. 
You can learn more about them here:
https://4sysops.com/archives/office-2016-installation-customize-and-deploy/
Make sure under remove following earlier versions that you remove all. 
Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have now had multiple versions of Office installed on this workstation.  You should now use OffScrub to ensure a clean starting point.

I didn't downvote this question, but others may have considered your use of a factory image as non-enterprise.

At this link: [Uninstall Office from a PC](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Uninstall-Office-from-a-PC-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), select Option 2 and download the `.diagcab` file.  Extract this with the tool of your choice, or just run it as a wizard.

This will iterate through your system and clean out any remnant of Office products.  It does not touch the user registry hive.